# SQL Query for hashtag links

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, buddypress

I have a (Wordpress and Buddypress) website under development. The site encourages use of hashtags in the Buddypress status updates.

I need to be able to show what's "trending" on the site, and list the most mentioned hashtags. These status updates with the hashtags are stored in a SQL database table, and could be any length. Is there a way I can search this database table for any hashtags, then list by most popular? Basically I need something like

```
SELECT # FROM status_updates WHERE (the status) INCLUDES (anything beginning with #) ORDER BY (most popular)
```

Comment: You will probably want to look at the `LIKE` keyword in SQL, but you're going to have to write a SQL query in any case.

Comment: SELECT...GROUP BY hastag ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Comment: Not familiar with your tables but something like this would do the trick if you knew tables: `SELECT status, COUNT(*) AS popularity FROM status_updates WHERE status LIKE '#%' GROUP BY status ORDER BY popularity`

Comment: I would advise against using any SQL to find hashtags, as you would need to extract **each** hashtag from the content and it won't be easy with SQL. A regular expression would be more flexible and it would be easier to implement it. String parsing is not a job for RDBMS, it's a task better suited for the application.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The table name is bp_activity, and I need to search the column 'content' where the column 'type' equals 'activity_update'

Comment: Have you created a custom table or are you using the existing meta tables (user and post meta)? If you're going down the meta route, take a look at the `WP_Meta_Query` class. It's V useful for querying meta values: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Thanks I will have a look. Its using the standard tables created by Buddypress.